# sort arraylist and compare in arraylist in java

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java. I have a problem with my code. I want to design my program but I stuck in ArrayList. How can I add a new price and display all food has price smaller or equals than the price of a new food? and sort the list f by price. Help me please, thank so much.

1.accept a new price named p: list all Food which have price <= p
2.sort list f ascending by price and output list after sorting

```
public class Food {

    //states
    private String name;
    private double price;

    //accessor
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    //mutator
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }


    //methods
    public Food() {
        name = "";
        price = 0;
    }

    public Food(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getSalePrice() {
        double tax = 0.07;//7%;
        if(name.toLowerCase().startsWith("k")) tax = 0.05;
        return price + price * tax;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.printf("%-20s%-10.1f ($)%-10.1f ($)\n",
                name,price,getSalePrice());
        //System.out.println(String.format("%-20s%-10.1f ($)%-10.1f ($)\n",
             //   name,price,getSalePrice()));
    }
    public int listp(ArrayList<Food> f, int priceP) { 
     int s,i,n;
     n = f.size();
     s = 0;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
       if(f.get(i).price > priceP) s++;  
     }
     return(s);
    }    
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //a list of food
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int MAX = 10;
        Food [] f = new Food[MAX];
        f[0] = new Food("BBQ",3.35);
        f[1] = new Food("KFC",3.3);
        f[2] = new Food("Ga 36",4.5);
        int n = 3;
        while(true) {          
            System.out.print("Enter food name: ");
            String name = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter food price: ");
            double price = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
            f[n] = new Food();
            //f[n].name = name;f[n].price = price;
            f[n].setName(name);
            f[n].setPrice(price);
            n++;
            System.out.print("Add more food (yes/no)? ");
            String s = in.nextLine();
            if(s.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) break;
        }
        //output list
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            f[i].print();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter price of food p:");
        double price = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println(listp(f,price));

    }
    public int listp(ArrayList<Food> f, int priceP) { 
        int s,i,n;
        n = f.size();
        s = 0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if(f.get(i).getPrice() > priceP) s++;  
        }
        return(s);
    }       
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList<Food>` and `Food []` are not the same thing

Comment: Check [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution where the array was converted to a list and the listp method was changed to use streams which are really a good fit for your requirements:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //a list of food
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Food> f = new ArrayList<>();
        f.add(new Food("BBQ", 3.35));
        f.add(new Food("KFC", 3.3));
        f.add(new Food("Ga 36", 4.5));
        int n = 3;
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter food name: ");
            String name = in.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter food price: ");
            double price = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
            Food food = new Food();
            //f[n].name = name;f[n].price = price;
            food.setName(name);
            food.setPrice(price);
            f.add(food);
            n++;
            System.out.print("Add more food (yes/no)? ");
            String s = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(s);
            if (s.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("no")) break;
        }
        System.out.print("Enter price of food p:");
        double price = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
        listp(f, price);

    }

    private static void listp(List<Food> f, double priceP) {
        f.stream()
                .filter(food -> food.getPrice() <= priceP)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Food::getPrice))
                .forEach(food -> System.out.printf("%s : %s%n", food.getName(), food.getPrice()));
    }
}
```

Here is a variation of the listp method which allows you to limit the list by a number:

```
private static void listp(List<Food> f, double priceP, int limit) {
    f.stream()
            .filter(food -> food.getPrice() <= priceP)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Food::getPrice))
            .limit(limit)
            .forEach(food -> System.out.printf("%s : %s%n", food.getName(), food.getPrice()));
}
```

This ensures that the printed out list is always as long as specified in the `limit` parameter.

Usage example:

```
listp(f, price, 2);
```

This will print a maximum of two items, even if the total list has more than that.

Comment: thank a lot. If i want to display list of food when I enter no, like this  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            f[i].print();
        } . How can I do it?

Comment: You can limit the number of printed out items using the changed `listp` method as described at the  bottom of the updated answer.

Comment: when I enter NO to break a loop while, I want to display the list food like this: //output list
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            f[i].print();.
display this list before listp(f, price); method

Comment: If you have a list with food you can simply print out the list to the console like so: `foodList.forEach(food -> System.out.printf("%s : %s%n", food.getName(), food.getPrice()));`

Comment: how can i use method:  public double getSalePrice() {
        double tax = 0.07;//7%;
        if(name.toLowerCase().startsWith("k")) tax = 0.05;
        return price + price * tax;
    }
in class Food to get saleprice

Comment: @AnMạnh: for example like this: `private static void printAllFood(List<Food> f) {
        f.forEach(food -> System.out.printf("%s : %s%n", food.getName(), food.getSalePrice()));
    }`

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
public List<Food> findFoodWhichPriceLessThan(Collection<Food> listOfFood, double price){
    return listOfFood.stream().filter(it -> it.getPrice() <= price).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

2.

```
  public void sortFoodByPrice(List<Food> listOfFood){
    Collections.sort(listOfFood, Comparator.comparingDouble(Food::getPrice));
  }
```

or

```
  public List<Food> sortFoodByPrice2(List<Food> listOfFood){
    return listOfFood.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Food::getPrice)).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```